# Localization forcing adds a random reals

Tags: set-theory, forcing

$\mathbf{Localization\,\,forcing}$, $\mathbb{Loc}$ consists of all pair $\langle \sigma, F\rangle$ such that  $\sigma\in([\omega]^{<\omega})^{<\omega}$ is a finite sequence with $|\sigma(n)|=n$ for all $n<|\sigma|$ and $F$ is
a finite set of reals with with $|F|\leq|\sigma|$. The order is given by $\langle\tau,G\rangle\leq\langle\sigma,F\rangle$ if and if $\tau\supseteq\sigma$, $G\supseteq F$, and $f(n)\in\tau(n)$ for all $f\in F$ and all $n\in|\tau|\smallsetminus|\sigma|$.

I would like to know where I can find that $\mathbb{Loc}$ adds a random real (many ramdon reals) or give me a suggestion how to prove this statements.

Can somebody help me on this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Where did you see the claim, and did you check the Bartoszynski–Judah book and Blass' chapter of the Handbook?

Comment: In the Bartoszynski–Judah book and Blass' chapter I didn't find anything

Comment: Try "[Localization forcing and Hechler’s theorem for the null ideal](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1360-6.pdf)" by Masaru Kada. It's a bit too long for me to go through it and see if that has the result, but a quick glance indicates that it may have a close enough argument.

Comment: Also "[The Cichoń Diagram for Degrees of Relative Constructibility](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06497v4)" by Corey Switzer, seems to have the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much Asaf!

Comment: If you do find the answers in those papers, please consider posting an answer to your question with the details. I don't have the time to do it properly.

Comment: Ok, I will do that